# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Symlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I don't want to place my config/database.yml file in GITHUB, rather to have it somewhere in the somewhere and do the symlink like below

config/databse.yml -> /var/www/database.yml

In the .elasticbeanstalk/00packages.config, I have following stuffs

```
commands:
  # install WKHTML
  03_command:
    command: yum install xz urw-fonts libXext openssl-devel libXrender
  04_command:
    command: wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
  05_command:
    command: tar -xJf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
  06_command:
    command: cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
  07_command:
    command: cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
```

Can I add symlink stuff here and does it work

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, none of the EB custom configurations allow you to perform operations after your application has been deployed. At the point at which `commands` are run, your application is still in `/var/app/ondeck`, so if you create a symlink under `/var/app/current`, it will be deleted when `ondeck` is renamed to `current`.

The only way around this limitation that I'm aware of is to put a file into the `appdeploy/post` hooks directory. In your case, it would look something like this:

**.ebextensions/01symlink.config**

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_create_symlink.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      ln -sf /var/www/database.yml /var/app/current/config/database.yml
```

Alternately, you could use a `commands` entry to **copy** the file from `/var/www` to `/var/app/ondeck` during the deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a symlink using `container_commands` and a relative path, which is your app's root directory by default. Although the `/var/app/current` directory does not exist, you can create a symlink and it will get moved to `/var/app/current` when the deploy completes. For example:

`container_commands:
  01symlink:
    command: sudo -u webapp ln -sf /var/www/database.yml ./config/database.yml`

Answer (score 0):

An better and far simpler solution is to use the `DATABASE_URL` environmental variable to [configure the database connection](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database). This is how Heroku for example "magically" connects your app to the database created by its postgres addon.

For example:

```
postgresql://somehost/some_database?username=foo&password=bar
```

Just leave the bare minimum in `database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
production:
  <<: *default
```

This makes it perfectly safe to check into version control.

And then set the env var through [environmental properties on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html).