# Keep Session when deploy new application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying a new application version in **Elastic Beanstalk**, I would like to keep the old instance running until the sessions expire. I mean: the new version will handle the new sessions, while the old version keep running, handling the old sessions. Is is possible?

BTW: Session stickiness is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**[Disclaimer: This strategy causes issues while using Elastic Beanstalk. Keeping it here anyway in case it may help someone.]**

You can use symlinks with the following deployment strategy to make it work:

- Use All at Once deployment. This will deploy new app to your current instance.
- Deploy your build app code to the/new/path/with/timestamp
- Create a symlink to point the current build folder to the new path and your site will now serve from new version. As current version code is also available, any requests sent won't face anomalies.
- You can cleanup previous version of the app after some time.

I am using this strategy for laravel and reactJS apps. Laravel sessions are kept even after deployments by keeping the storage folder.

You can read more about [this strategy from a deployment service provider](https://www.deployhq.com/blog/setting-up-zero-downtime-deployments).

Comment: This question is about Elastic Beanstalk which manages the deployments for you. Symlinks wouldn't work here, and that method would only work for PHP applications anyway.

Comment: @MarkB, Just FYI, this strategy works for Python Django and a number of other apps as well. OP is more concerned about solving the problem.

Comment: you can't solve the problem on Elastic Beanstalk using symlinks.

Comment: We can use symlinks inside Elastic Beanstalk, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44235457/9907481. But there's another limitation that causes problem, i.e. the new version of app is renamed by EB to to the current version possibly removing the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

How would you handle a really long lived session? If somebody's session lasted for hours would you want to keep an old server around all that time until that user logged out?

If you just want to keep a user from being logged out due to a deployment, (i.e. keep their session from being reset), then I suggest storing the session outside of Elastic Beanstalk, for example in DynamoDB or Redis. Depending on your programming language and web server, there should be some libraries available for accomplishing that.

There are several [Elastic Beanstalk deployment options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rolling-version-deploy.html) you can pick from. Traffic Splitting sounds the closest to what you are looking for. However these primarily deal with keeping servers up to handle traffic during a deployment, and canary testing the new version before completing the deployment. They do not maintain user sessions on one server until the session expires.